# android rounded corner textview with perfect round in the corner

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

How to show a textview with rounded corner rectangle as shown in the orginal image
[image]

in the above (original) picture, the button 2's left and right rounded corner are correctly shaped but in my code the **left and right rounded corners are not shaped correctly**

[image]

in the second picture I need to do more rounded as the 1st image. how can I do with following drawable?

drawable code (green_bg.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#19D8C8" />
    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#19D8C8" />
</shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
.......
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qmap_2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/no_color" />
    ......
```

Comment: Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/pavlospt/RoundedLetterView).

Comment: In what way are they not shaped correctly?

Comment: @Karakuri, please compare two images rounded corners. 1st is more rounded but 2nd is not rounded as 1st one.

Answer (score 13):

create a file  round.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#176d7a" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

now set the background of textview like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qmap_2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:textColor="@color/no_color" />
```

it should work

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!
Do you know if there's a way to make the background have a minimal aspect ratio of 1:1? So that it's always a circle or wider.

Comment: you can add size tag inside shape like this <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>

Answer (score 4):

Change the **corner** **radius** to a much higher value i.e 100dp

```
<corners android:radius="100dip" />
```

[image]